# How to avoid getting car light directly in eyes when on bike without using polarized glasses?

Tags: car, light

When I come back from university, mostly it is late night. I am on bike and when I enter an area where there is no road light and having darkness every where. When a car came in front of me then it was irritating me and it blindens me for few seconds. How can I avoid this situation without using polarized glasses? Because in our country there is very rear.

Comment: Polarised glasses won't stop light getting into your eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you avoid having the car lights in your eyes at all - you can usually see when one is going to turn a corner or crest a hill and can avert your head. A peak on your bike helmet helps as you can just drop your head to look down, but even without a peak, your eyelids are pretty effective (don't close your eyes though :-)

If this is not possible, I have reasonable success with looking straight at the car - this does mean the cones in my retina can't then give me any useful info for a while, but as they are less useful at night anyway, at least the rods, which are better in low light levels, still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hand free (depends on the build of the bike) you can hold your hand in front of your eyes, screening out the car lights but allowing you to see something around your hand.
In the worst cases you may have to stop and stand waiting for the car to get past.

If it is safe to do so, closing your eyes for a short time might bring relief, but be careful if you are still moving, on a bike you are soon off the right track.